# Has the Palestinian Authority issued some official statement on the situation in May 2021?

Tags: israel, middle-east, palestine, hamas

Has the Palestinian Authority (PA) issued some official statement about the current situation? In particular, Hamas et al's rocket attacks on Israel? Google didn't return anything (although it was hard to phrase a good search for this).

Answer (score 36):

The nominal leader of the Palestinian Authority, Mahmoud Abbas, has consistently opposed the rocket campaign of Hamas, since at least [2005](https://www.nytimes.com/2005/07/19/world/middleeast/abbas-criticizes-hamas-radicals-in-harsh-terms.html), and [continues to do so](https://nationalpost.com/news/world/israel-middle-east/mahmoud-abbas-slams-hamas-over-rocket-attacks-on-israel-what-are-you-trying-to-achieve).  This conflict underlines the extent to which the Palestinian Authority is divided. There is more than a little truth in the Monty Python parody in which the "People's Front of Judea" hates the "Judean People's Front" more than the occupying Romans.  Fatah and Hamas are strongly opposed to each other.

Moreover, even within Fatah, Abbas can't claim to have unified support. As the [Irish times notes](https://www.irishtimes.com/news/world/middle-east/latest-conflict-exposes-impotence-of-fatah-dominated-palestinian-authority-1.4565448) The ageing Fatah leadership has little support among younger Palestinians. The PA is split three ways.

So Abbas and the Fatah leadership oppose the rockets while stating that they will "continue to do everything possible to defend our people and stop this aggressive occupation from our country and our sanctities".  This all needs to be read in the context of the cancelled PA elections which had been scheduled for 22 May, and in which it had been expected that Abbas would have lost his dominant position.

Comment: Thank you, do you have sources or examples when Abbas criticises Hamas' rockets?

Comment: /ive idded some western news reports, from 2005 and from 2014

Comment: RE conflict between PA and Hamas, [this](https://www.gatestoneinstitute.org/17466/gaza-reconstruction-funds) may be relevant: _The Palestinian Authority and Hamas, in short, are saying that they do not trust each other regarding the hundreds of millions of dollars that have been promised by Egypt and other countries to contribute to the reconstruction effort in the Gaza Strip._